# How can I generate a random number greater or less than a previous random number?

Tags: java, random

I am currently in a Java 1 class, and made a number guessing game for fun. Basic take input, tells you if it's too high or low, then lets you guess again. I thought it would be interesting to make it so the computer guesses as well, then compares your guesses to its. I have all of the generation and comparing working, but it continues to guess numbers without taking the greater/less than into account, which I want to add. I have:

```
    public static void autoPlay(int num){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int guess1 = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int counter = 0;
    while(guess1 != num){
        counter++;
        int guess = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int initialHigh = 100;
        int initialLow = 0;
        // I want it to guess smart and recognize if it were too high or too low, and generate a number between there

        if(guess1 > num){   
            int newGuess = rand.nextInt(initialHigh - guess1) + 1;
        }else if(guess1 < num){
            int newGuess2 = rand.nextInt(initialLow + guess1) + 1;
        }
        initialLow = guess;
        initialHigh = guess;
        guess1 = guess;
        System.out.printf("%3d", guess1);
    }
    System.out.println("It took " + counter + " guesses to get the correct number");
}
```

I can't tell what is wrong with my math in the if statement, or if theres just something I can call to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplicates, then generate the appropriate numbers and shuffle it (for a full random function):

```
List<Integer> values = IntStream.range(0, /* max */).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(values);
int guesses = values.indexOf(/* some number */) + 1;
```

The list would be fully randomly ordered, so you'd guess in order of the randomized list, thus the index is the number of guesses (-1, since it's 0-indexed)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are just using the same bounds for the random number. You generate new bounds here:

```
if(guess1 > num){   
            int newGuess = rand.nextInt(initialHigh - guess1) + 1;
        }else if(guess1 < num){
            int newGuess2 = rand.nextInt(initialLow + guess1) + 1;
        }
```

But you don't use them at all, you just reuse the values you had before:

```
        initialLow = guess;
        initialHigh = guess;
        guess1 = guess;
        System.out.printf("%3d", guess1);
```

You must use the values produced by `newGuess` and `newGuess2` (althought you don't need these two variables, declare one of them outside the if and just assign a value to it inside the if). Then you will be using updated values.

I also noticed that you created many variables that store the same value, such as `guess` and `guess1`, which you don't need, you just need to declare one of them and reuse later (so you can save memory : ) ).

Also, I see a problem in setting initialHigh and initialLow both as `guess`, why would you want that?

Try to review your code logic and clean up some variables, some of them are duplicated.

But, in summary, I think the problem is that you are generating new bounds but you are not using them.